# Bootstrap.js tabs doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm pretty lost with Bootstrap.js tabs. I have got this html:

```
<ul class="button-menu" id="stores" data-tabs="tabs">

</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="storesGoods">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="store0">test</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="store1">test2</div>   
</div>
```

And I generate with JS it's content

```
function updateShop(){
    var actualStores = "";
    for (var i=0;i<actualTown.store.length;i++){
        actualStores=actualStores + "<li><a href='#store"+i+"' data-toggle='stores'>"+actualTown.store[i].name+"</a></li>"
        $("#store"+i).html(actualTown.store[i].listGoods());
    };
    $("#stores").html(actualStores);
};
```

When I view my html via Chrome, I see that it generated this:

```
<ul class="button-menu" id="stores" data-tabs="tabs">
    <li><a href="#store0" data-toggle="stores">24/7 Store</a></li>
    <li><a href="#store1" data-toggle="stores">Liquiro</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="storesGoods">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="store0">
        <p>24/7 Store: All day, all night, every day!</p>
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>item</th>
                    <th>price</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bottled Water</td>
                    <td>0.84</td>
                    <td><a class="buy" onclick="buyToInventory(d1)">buy</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Raush Juice</td>
                    <td>0.9</td>
                    <td><a class="buy" onclick="buyToInventory(d2)">buy</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bohemia Chips</td>
                    <td>0.7</td>
                    <td><a class="buy" onclick="buyToInventory(e2)">buy</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Vodka Alosuth</td>
                    <td>2.7</td>
                    <td><a class="buy" onclick="buyToInventory(d3)">buy</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pilsner beer (10°)</td>
                    <td>0.8</td>
                    <td><a class="buy" onclick="buyToInventory(d7)">buy</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pilsner beer (12°)</td>
                    <td>0.98</td>
                    <td><a class="buy" onclick="buyToInventory(d8)">buy</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bread</td>
                    <td>1.2</td>
                    <td><a class="buy" onclick="buyToInventory(e1)">buy</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Rosito Schnap</td>
                    <td>0.68</td>
                    <td><a class="buy" onclick="buyToInventory(d10)">buy</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="store1">
        <p>Liquiro: Bad day? Liquiro will fix that, buy some boost for yourself and some chips.</p>
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>item</th>
                    <th>price</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Vodka Alosuth</td>
                    <td>2.7</td>
                    <td><a class="buy" onclick="buyToInventory(d3)">buy</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pilsner beer (10°)</td>
                    <td>0.8</td>
                    <td><a class="buy" onclick="buyToInventory(d7)">buy</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pilsner beer (12°)</td>
                    <td>0.98</td>
                    <td><a class="buy" onclick="buyToInventory(d8)">buy</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Rosito Schnap</td>
                    <td>0.68</td>
                    <td><a class="buy" onclick="buyToInventory(d10)">buy</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

So it's generated as it's supossed to be but switching tabs doesn't work, when I click on something in `ul #stores` it doesnt change tab, it just add to url `www.something.com/#store0` and nothing happens.

Does anyone know how to make these tabs working, I'm totally lost.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing like `data-toggle="store"` in [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs), it should be `data-toggle="tab"`, and the plugin will figure itself out which is the right target, via the `href` attribute.

Their example is quite straightforward, just follow it.

Comment: Thanks, it works, I though that tabs should have different data-toggles, because I already have another tab menu. :)